# Authenticate Service Principal with certificate stored in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, powershell, certificate, azure-keyvault, service-principal

I am trying to authenticate a local hadoop cluster to Azure using a service principal and certificate authentication. I have created a service principal, and put had the key vault create the certificate. I know how to get that information once I am authenticated, but I am trying to figure out how I would re-authenticate automatically once the certificate expires.

Comment: Add a second certificate that is allowed to auth to the service principal with staggered expiration dates, then failover to the second certificate if the first fails to auth.

Comment: That's brilliant.